# Best possible way to get two arrays merged

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby

```
temp1 = [1,2,3,4]
temp2 = [4,3,2,1]
```

Two array merged with following output

```
temp3 = [ [1,4], [2,3], [3,2], [4,1] ]
```

It's not that temp array will have only 4 elements.
It can have 5-5, 6-6 elements not 5-6 in both array.

Comment: Is your problem only for two arrays with 4 elements? If not, I don't understand how it generalizes to larger arrays.

Comment: For larger array also one to one mapping. Nested array will be only having 2 elements.

Comment: I don't see the logic behind this transformation

Comment: What's the pattern? Why is 4 with 1, but 3 with 3?

Comment: It is simple map temp1 first element with temp2 first element and so on. In array of elements.

Comment: I don't understand.  What is the 1-1 map? It's seems that `temp1[0]->temp2[0]` and `temp1[-1]->temp2[-1]`, but the map is different for other elements. Because the example has only 4 elements in each array, it's not clear if (for example) `temp1[1]` maps to `temp2[1+1]` or to  `temp2[n-1-1]`, where `n = temp1.size #=> 4`. You need to edit to clarify the map, preferable with larger arrays.

Comment: Please check to make sure `temp3` is correct.

Comment: So sorry guy's... I mistyped temp3. edited just now.

Comment: It's not a big deal @Cary. It can happen in hurry... probably can happen with you in future. We are not here for taking some one on edge...we are here for helping out for problems.

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it happens to me in future, as it's already happened several times in the past. If we couldn't forgive others for that, SO would have very few members.  Sometimes it's an example with a small mistake, other times it's a statement that, unbeknownst to the writer, can be interpreted in other ways. I've come to realize that if I'm thinking, "Why don't these people get it? It's so simple.", it's time to double-check what I've written.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. Yours suggestions and mine mistakes makes me and people a better learners. Appreciate thought process.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is exactly the functionality provided by the [zip](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-zip) method:

```
>> temp1.zip(temp2)
=> [[1, 4], [2, 3], [3, 2], [4, 1]]
```

Comment: Exactly what `zip` is for.

Comment: The only problem is that this does not return the array the OP wants. (`transpose` will produce the same output.)

Comment: @CarySwoveland good observation! I don't know how I missed that. Transpose doesn't quite get us there either though. I'm hoping the question is just a typo, otherwise it seems underspecified...